# Copying UIAlertController button behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating custom dialogs for my app and some what copying UIAlertController in some aspects. How should I implement the behaviour where when you click any action from alert/dialog the controller is dismissed.

How does Apple do it without making us manually specify for each action  handler that it should dismiss the view controller?

I have like them one view controller class:

```
@interface MyAlertViewController : UIViewController
- (void)addAction:(MyAlertAction *) action;

//...
```

And one class for the actions:

```
@interface MyAlertAction : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(nullable NSString *)title handler:(void (^)(MyAlertAction *action))handler;
```

EDIT: How I did it taking in accord the answer feedback:

```
//MYAlertViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    for (int i = 0; i < self.actions.count; i++) {
        MYAlertAction *action = self.actions[i];

        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        button.tag = i;//this here is how I link the button to the action
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(executeAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [actionStackView addArrangedSubview:button];

        [self.actionsStackView addArrangedSubview:actionLayout];
    }
}

- (void)executeAction:(UIButton *) sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        //this is where the button tag comes in handy
        MYAlertAction *actionToExecute = self.actions[sender.tag];
        actionToExecute.actionHandler();
    }];
}
```

Comment: Each button on the screen is associated with a action.  When the button is triggered, the controller is dismissed and the action triggered

Comment: BTW if the execution is in the order you say. How does the action execute after you dismiss the controller which is the thing that has the reference of the action?

Comment: Well I dislike the use of tags and indexes. Personally I would store each block in the button itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does Apple do it without making us manually specify for each action handler that it should dismiss the view controller?

You are confusing two different things:

- The UIAlertAction's last initialization parameter, the `handler` parameter, which you get to set from outside, and which is to run after the button is tapped and after the alert has been dismissed. It is a *block*.
- The actual *button's* action, which the client can't set or see. It is configured by the alert controller. It is a *selector*.

So now, *you* play the role of the UIAlertController. In your

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(nullable NSString *)title handler:(void (^)(MyAlertAction *action))handler;
```

the client hands you the *first* action I mentioned, the block, and you store it for later execution. But the *second* action, the button action, the selector, is entirely up to you as you create the button in response to this call.

So as you configure the button, just configure it with a target/action pair that calls into a method of your view controller, just as for any button. In method, when called, the view controller dismisses itself, and in the completion handler of the dismissal, calls the block.

Comment: In this case the dismissal callback would have to know which action to execute. To know that I will have to relate in some way the button clicked to the action that needs to happen. This comes from the fact that all button selectors will go trough that one selector in the ViewController. I could do that by numbering the buttons using their tags or sth and then using that number to get the action from the array where the actions are stored in the ViewController. My code is more 'tangled' as MyAlertAction actually builds the button and  MyAlertViewController takes the button from there.

Comment: So now you need me to tell you how to store and retrieve the block?

Comment: I am curious how apple does it. Because their handler block is not in the public interface but the AlertViewController class knows about it. I just declare it public in the MyAlertAction interface. They probably 'abuse' some mechanic to execute private methods of other classes?